# Assign a static method from another class to a prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6, prototype

Let's say I have two classes with slightly different static methods:

```
// FooA.js
export class FooA {
  static myFunc() {
    // logic here...
  }
}

// FooB.js
export class FooB {
  static myFunc() {
    // different logic here
  }
}
```

Now I have a utils class or some sort of handler that needs to import `myFunc()` based on a conditional:

```
export class Utils {
  if(conditional) {
    Utils.prototype.myFunc = FooA.myFunc;
  } else {
    Utils.prototype.myFunc = FooB.myFunc;
  }
}
```

When looking up documentation on how `Class.prototype.functionName` is used, the examples always show prototypes being assigned a function that's declared in that file. I'm looking for a way to assign functions to a prototype that have been declared in another class.

Comment: You'll have to make the assignment to the prototype *outside* the `class` declaration, but otherwise it should work pretty much like your example.

Comment: Are you sure you need to assign a static method as an instance method of another class? If `Utils` is just a collection of utility functions, it should not be a `class` at all.

Comment: Some working code samples would really help! I'm trying variations of the suggestions but I can't seem to get the syntax right. There aren't any examples online that I can find either.